# Collect list of property of an Array of objects

Tags: java, android

i need a list o string like `String PersonName` from class `Person class`. i want to Export `List<Person>` to `List<String>` that contains `PersonName` But i can't use Stream and Collector because my min Api is 21. How can i do this?

Comment: `List<String> names = new ArrayList<>(); for (Person p : persons) { names.add(p.getName()); }`

Comment: What have you tried so far? It is very simple using classical iteration.

Comment: @AmitBera Nothing only stream library that i found in other threads and i can't use it.

Comment: Please read how to write for loop in java. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need streams for this, a simple imperative approach would be:

```
List<String> namesAccumulator = new ArrayList<>();
for(Person person : myPeopleList)
     namesAccumulator.add(person.getName());
```

Comment: namesAccumulator is actually a List<String>